# Symfony Invokable controllers called with render_esi

Tags: symfony, controller, invoke

With Symfony, there is a possibility to create [invokable controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#invokable-controllers).

For some blocks like header or footer, i call my controller with twig function like this `render(controller('App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController'))` and it works.

But if i do the same with `render_esi(controller('App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController'))` i've this following error :

```
Cannot use object of type App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController as array
```

Is it possible to use invokable controller with `render_esi` ?

My controller :

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use ScemBundle\Helpers\EsiHelper;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Twig\Error\Error;

/**
 *
 */
final class MyInvokableController
{
    use RepositoriesTrait;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EsiHelper $esiHelper
     * @param TwigEngine $twig
     *
     * @return Response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request, EsiHelper $esiHelper, TwigEngine $twig): Response
    {
        $params = $this->getSomeContent();
        $content = $twig->render('@path/to/template.html.twig', $params);

        $response = new Response();
        $response
            ->setContent($content)
            ->setPublic()
            ->setSharedMaxAge(65536);

        return $esiHelper->builEsiHeader($listItems, $response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController::__invoke` work?  And are you sure your esiHelper is working correctly?  I assume you intentionally skipped the code for $listItems?

Comment: And it's working like this !! Thank you.
For resume, with `render` function `render(controller('App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController'))` and with `render_esi` `{{ render_esi(controller('App\\Controller\\MyInvokableController::__invoke')) }}`